# How to grab text corresponding to checkboxes in selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, checkbox, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium webdriver to run script.

I have a scenario where I want to grab text corresponding to checkboxes.

For a single checkbox I am using getAttribute() to capture text as given in below code and it is working fine.

```
String referenceIn3DPage=Driver.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[3][@class='some-class']//input")).getAttribute("id");
```

Does getAttribute invalid in case of findElements() ?

How to capture text for multiple checkbox?

Screenshot of checkbox:
[image]

HTML screenshot:

[image]

As you can see in screenshot I want the attribute - id to capture my text.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly use **value** parameter to get text of checkbox :

```
String referenceIn3DPage=Driver.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[3][@class='some-class']//input")).getAttribute("value");
```

**Output :** OSCP120  [If given xpath is of first check box]

Comment: I want list of text corresponding to all checkboxes, not of a particular checkbox.
I want value like OSCP120,PCFD030 and so on.

Comment: Then you will have iterate using List<WebElements> instead of single string.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more?

Comment: Using size(), I found the count of checkbox.
Now, problem is how to iterate referenceIn3DPage from 1 to 9?

`int count=Driver.driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[3][@class='some-class']//input")).size();

   
System.out.println("the count="+count);
  
   

 for(int i=1;i<=count;i++)
{
    referenceIn3DPage=Driver.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[3][@class='some-class']//input")).getAttribute("id"); 
    

System.out.println("the value in 3d= "+referenceIn3DPage);
     
}`

Comment: the count is returning 9.

Answer (score 1):

Just taking the code from you another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33935756/how-to-loop-through-xpath-expression) and modifying it.

```
String referenceIn3DPage =null;
int count=Driver.driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[3][@class='viewer3d-demo-commercial-references-checkboxes']//input")).size();
System.out.println("the count="+count);

for(int i=1;i<=count;i++)
{
  referenceIn3DPage=Driver.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[3][@class='viewer3d-demo-commercial-references-checkboxes']/div["+i+"]/label/input")).getAttribute("id"); 
  System.out.println("the value in 3d= "+referenceIn3DPage);
}
```

Kindly run the above code and let me know if it gives you the expected result.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Manu. Code is working fine. I did mistake in evaluating xpath.

Comment: Welcome! Yep, you were doing fine, just a typo :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try : `.getAttribute("value");`