# How to loop through xpath expression?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I have a xpath expression:

```
referenceIn3DPage=Driver.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[3][@class='some-class']/div[1]//label")).getAttribute("id");
```

I want to loop from `1` to `9` for `div[]`.

Below is my code to loop `div[i]` from `1 to 9`:

```
String referenceIn3DPage =null;

int count=Driver.driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[3][@class='some-class']//input")).size();

System.out.println("the count="+count);


for(int i=1;i<=count;i++)
{
referenceIn3DPage=Driver.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[3][@class='some-class']/div["+i+"]//label/input")).getAttribute("id"); 

System.out.println("the value in 3d= "+referenceIn3DPage);


}
```

But, it is not working as per my requirement. I want script to display OSP102 and 8 more reference ID (please refer to link given below for list of reference IDs.)

The output:

```
the count=9
the value in 3d= OSCP102
```

NOTE: Please refers to my original question for better clarity.

[How to grab text corresponding to checkboxes in selenium webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33932649/how-to-grab-text-corresponding-to-checkboxes-in-selenium-webdriver/33932843?)

Comment: "it is not working" as in... what? You get exceptions? You get no results? You get wrong results? What results do you get?

Comment: What error you are getting? your loop seems fine to me.

Comment: @HelpingHands  updated the question with the output.

Comment: `the count=9` Where does that line come from? The code you posted appears to be incomplete. It also does not seem to contain the problem. Please post more of your code.

Comment: @JanDoerrenhaus Updated the question with script and link to original question.

Comment: You are not iterating properly over the divs. `//div[3][@class='some-class']/div["+i+"]//label/input` seems to be iterating over the wrong div. Make sure this some class is `viewer3d-demo-commercialxyz....`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify your code by using `findElements()` and looping through the first 9 `div` elements which your xpath will fetch. Just make sure your xpath is correct.

```
referenceIn3DPage=Driver.driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[3][@class='some-class']/div"));

for(WebElement e : referenceIn3DPage.sublist(0,9)) { 
    String idVal = e.findElement(By.ByTagName("label").getAttribute("id"));
    System.out.println(idVal);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first check the xpath on the website and make sure its selecting the expected results.
 I recommend you [FireBug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/?src=search) + [FirePath](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/firepath/) which are doing a great job for that.